# Disable HTML encoding of substitution_data

Tags: sparkpost

After we switched from Mandrill to SparkPost we encountered issues when sending emails using `transmission`. In Mandrill `merge_vars` were not HTML encoded and we sometimes put HTML in them, however in SparkPost `substitution_data` does appear to be HTML encoded and it's messing some of our emails. Is there a global setting that allows to turn this off or at least disable it for a `transmission`?

**Edit:** <s>I forgot to mention that we use [csharp-sparkpost](https://github.com/SparkPost/csharp-sparkpost) library, which means it might be a problem directly related to the library rather than SparkPost API and I need to investigate it further.</s>

**Edit2:** I tested sending an email directly using JSON and the result was the same, so I can conclude that the HTML encoding is done by SparkPost and not by the c# library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can render HTML in substitution variables without escaping by using 3 braces around your variables.  e.g. With this in your transmission:

```
{
  "substitution_data": {
    "firstName": "<em>Jimbo</em>"
  },
  "content": {
    "html": "<p>Hi {{{firstName}}}</p>"
  }
}
```

...you get this in your HTML message body:

```
<p>Hi <em>Jimbo</em></p>
```

There are more details in the SparkPost reference docs: https://developers.sparkpost.com/api/#/introduction/substitutions-reference/escaping-html-values

Comment: This is really helpful. As for variable name case sensitivity, I ended writing a regex that scans through our template and replaces occurrences of substitution variable names with their correct case, so my college can keep messing them up to his heart's content.